# Questions about batch_size in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, batchsize

I tried out PyTorch and wanted to write a program for PHM 2010. But, the result of program is not good. There is a problem  that the prediction becomes worse as the batch_size increasing.
The dataset is PHM2010.There are 315 sets of samples, and the input of each set of samples has seven signals and the output is the wear value.There are six tool wear values in the data set, which are C1,C2,C3,C4,C5 and C6.Among them, 1,4 and 6 have real wear values as supervised learning.This code takes the C1 dataset.
The neural network uses the convolutional neural network.
When the batch_size is 1, the predicted value is close to that in the Keras framework. However, the predicted value will drift away from the real value with the batch_size increasing.

Code in github: https://github.com/charmerphil/CNN-keras-and-pytorch.git
As shown in the figure below.

```
Figure 1, batch_size = 1  pytorch
Figure 2, batch_size = 2  pytorch
Figure 3, batch_size = 3  pytorch 
Figure 4, batch_size = 5  pytorch
Figure 5, batch_size = 10 pytorch
Figure 6, batch_size = 10 keras
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you average your loss according to batch size? Or, just using sum?